# What word or phrase should be used to describe this website line?

Tags: internet

This website has a line that says "David -> Labs -> Lab".

What word or phrase should be used to describe this line?  A menu line?  A navigation line?  A page path line?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a **breadcrumb**.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)) :

> A **breadcrumb** or **breadcrumb trail** is a graphical control element frequently used as a navigational aid in user interfaces and on web pages. It allows users to keep track and maintain awareness of their locations within programs, documents, or websites.
>   The term originates from the trail of bread crumbs left by Hansel and Gretel in the fairy tale of the same name.

Lots of examples (including screenshots) at http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Breadcrumbs.